# How to convert a nvarchar(255) to YYYY-MM-DD format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, format, nvarchar

I need help in writing a SQL statement to convert date column which is of type `nvarchar(255)` into a date type 'yyyy-mm-dd' format

I tried all the alternatives available across stackoverflow relating this topic but couldn't find a solution for my dataset.

The sample data:

```
Fri, 23 Oct, 2020
Mon, 19 Oct, 2020
Fri, 16 Oct, 2020
Tue, 20 Oct, 2020
Tue, 27 Oct, 2020
```

To date format:

```
2020-Oct-23
2020-Oct-19
2020-Oct-16
2020-Oct-20
2020-Oct-27
```

I am using SQL server 2014.

Comment: You should have a 1 digit day too in the sample data. Like `Fri, 4 Dec, 2020`.

Comment: The real question here is why are you storing dates as a `(n)varchar` at all. Date and time data types don't have a "format" they are binary values. Fix the design, use the correct data type and have the presentation layer determine the **display** format, not the RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server as pretty flexible default rules for converting strings to dates.  However, it doesn't recognize the leading day of week.  So, if you remove that, it is easy enough:

```
select convert(date, stuff('Fri, 23 Oct, 2020', 1, 5, ''))
```

Or referring to a column:

```
select convert(date, stuff(datecol, 1, 5, ''))
```

This produces a `date` which you can then format however you like using either `format()` or `convert()`.  However, I recommend keeping the format as YYYY-MM-DD.  This works for range comparisons and for `ORDER BY`.  And you really want dates to be represented as dates.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4e92382aa01af17aeccf95607bf420a3) is a db<>fiddle.